# How to create colour and size select box for product Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

[image]

In that product, I need a new color box "red" how can do it. here I got color and size  attribute

```
 [0] => Array
                        (
                            [product_super_attribute_id] => 57
                            [value_index] => 18
                            [label] => Purple
                            [default_label] => Purple
                            [store_label] => Purple
                            [is_percent] => 0
                            [pricing_value] => 
                            [use_default_value] => 1
                        )

                )

            [attribute_id] => 92
            [attribute_code] => color
            [frontend_label] => Color
            [store_label] => Color
        )
```

but unable to understand how can I use it and where to edit. 
please let me know step by step I  am new in Magento.

Comment: Create one more simple product with option red and assign that simple product to your existing(display) configurable product.